# Baking Procedural Mossy Dirt Material

Tags: texturing, materials, baking, pbr

According to the tutorial [*"Procedural Mossy Dirt Material (Blender Tutorial)"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAC_amUh__w) I created the Mossy Dirt material. Next, I try to bake the material according to the [*"Bake Procedural Materials to Tileable Texture Maps (Blender & Gimp Tutorial)"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAjGtE678o0&t) tutorial.

[image]

I use the baking sequence suggested by the author (Diffuse, Roughness, Normal) at a texture resolution of 4096x4096. I also use the **Node Wrangler** *"Shift + Ctrl + T"* combination to create a new material. The result is an unsatisfactory picture. The color does not match the original.

[image]

Roughness is baked in a single color.

[image]

My guess is that these errors are due to the complex stuff that the two **Principled BSDF** nodes use.

[image]

Do these materials require a different baking algorithm? Or am I doing something wrong? Blender version 3.5.1.

Comment: I am attaching a file with material. Maybe someone wants to take a look. Mossy_Dirt_PBR. https://blend-exchange.com/b/yO8aqQlz/
I removed all textures from the file and HDRI. Because the file was very large and did not go to the exchange server.