# Cubby Long and Cloth Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision, hardware, mixamo

There is an idea to create a full-fledged short cartoon about a chibi dude from Shaolin.

[image]

The first episode is "*A Dude Goes Down a Mountain to Get Water*." The sketch can be viewed here. [*Episode one*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjPHBmC_LOw).

Information about **Cloth Simulation** is taken from **YouTube** tutorials. [*First*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg). [*Second*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYKp8QTDTyw).

I have the following sequence of MIXAMO animations. 5 down the stairs + 3 walking + 7 down the stairs + 1 jumping down. The total duration of the episode is 600-700 frames.

The "*[Down the Stairs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249262/fixing-descending-stairs-walk-from-mixamo)*" animation on MIXAMO is broken. I aligned the legs frame by frame and made Insert Keyframes ***I*** >> *All Channels* in the **Pose Editor**.

The character has several parts inserted. I attach the black sneakers immediately, before sending them to Mixamo, using *Ctrl+J*.

[image]

Next, after the animation, I attach the following elements to the armature bones (*Ctrl+P*). Eyes, eyebrows, wrapping on the left and right legs and arms, belt, buckets. The T-shirt and pants have **Cloth Simulation**. The dude himself has the **Collision** modifier.

[image]

Animations with Mixamo have 30 fps. The overall scene has 24 fps.

All attempts to run the clothing simulation are unsuccessful. Clothes become crumpled, fall inside the character, and fly away somewhere.

[image]

I would like specialists to assess my situation and give further direction. Perhaps I'm violating the correct sequence of operations when assembling the scene? Or does the difference in FPS in the scene have an impact? Is it possible that the **Cloth Simulation** doesn't support such long animation sequences? Perhaps it is worth using alternative software - **AccuRIG**, for example?

Perhaps my equipment is not suitable for this project? I have an *Intel i5 8400* CPU plus a *GeForce GTX 1660*.

Maybe it's worth abandoning **Cloth Simulation** and using simpler models? *[Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvHvcg8WV1Y)*. Or is it worth purchasing an additional addon?

Related questions. *[First](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249262/fixing-descending-stairs-walk-from-mixamo)*. *[Second.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294843/baking-procedural-mossy-dirt-material)*

Non-profit, educational project. Blender version 4.0.2.

Comment: I'm afraid this is way too broad for our format on Stack Exchange.. an archive of ranked answers to specific questions. Any **specific** question, with an answer that is a **solution** to it, is on-point, here. If you got started on your project, and at some point encountered a particular problem, or wanted to know the best way to achieve a particular effect ... that's where we can help.